# ImmutableJS set in Map with deep comparison

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have two deeply nested data objects, such that:

```
myMap.get("dataKey") === maybeNewData // false
Immutable.is(myMap.get("dataKey"), maybeNewData) //maybe true
```

I want to replace myMap.get("dataKey") with `maybeNewData` only if some of the nested values changed.  Is there a syntactically precise way to do this?  For example (method doesn't exist):

```
const maybeNewMap = myMap.setIfDeepDifferent("dataKey", maybeNewData);
```

Or do I have to do it like this?:

```
if (!Immutable.is(myMap.get("dataKey"), maybeNewData)) {
  maybeNewMap = myMap.set("dataKey", maybeNewData);
}
```

Comment: So what you want to do is a deep comparison?

Comment: Yes.  And I want to replace `data` either completely, or not at all.  So I can't use myMap.deepMerge, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which is slightly better: using `update` provides a place for the `.is` check:

```
const maybeNewMap = myMap.update("dataKey", (data) => {
  return !Immutable.is(data, maybeNewData) ? maybeNewData : data;
});
```

I'm still curious if there is a more succinct way to express this.

Comment: Ternary operator?

Comment: That helps a bit (I updated my response to reflect that), but I am more curious to know if immutableJS provides a utility to do this operation in one line.

Comment: I think it's not there because of the assumption is that you're using Immutable.is for equality checks? Wouldn't this update be roughly equivalent to just doing myMap.set, as long as the places you were checking for equality used Immutable.is?